# how to generate a compare function from a pointer to member function?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

Writing compare functions for STL algorithms & containers is tedious.

For simple objects such as this,

```
struct Person
{
    int id;
    string name;
    string surname;
    string get_full_name(); // name then surname
};
```

I have to type the same function call for both `lhs` and `rhs`:

```
vector<Person> v = { ... };
std::sort( v.begin(), v.end(), [](const Object &lhs, const Object &rhs) {
    return lhs.get_full_name() < rhs.get_full_name();   // tedious
} );
```

I would like to be able to compose a **compare function/functor** using a pointer-to-member-function or pointer-to-member-data. Maybe like so:

```
std::sort( v.begin(), v.end(), make_compare_functor( &Object::get_full_name ));
std::sort( v.begin(), v.end(), make_compare_functor( &Object::surname ));
```

I've tried to implement it like so:

```
template <class R, class T>
struct CompareFunctor {
    R (T::*fp)();
    bool operator() (const T& lhs, const T& rhs) { 
           return lhs->*fp() < rhs->*fp();
    }
};

// helper function
template <class R, class T>
CompareFunctor<R,T> make_compare_functor(R(T::*fp)()) {
    return CompareFunctor<R,T> { fp };
}
```

but it fails to instantiate `T` for *any* of these cases

```
auto functor1 = make_compare_functor( &Person::get_full_name );
auto functor2 = make_compare_functor( &std::string::size );
```

(the error message is like: `'make_compare_functor': no matching overloaded function found ...  note: could be 'const Person' or 'Person'`)

**can anybody guide me how to to compose a compare function/functor using a pointer-to-member-function please?**

It should preferably be STL based -- no Boost or another library.

Comment: *no Boost or another library.* -- Well, if there was something in Boost that solved your problem, wouldn't you need to simply look at the Boost source code and see what they did to answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, but you'll need to overload `make_compare_functor` to accept both a pointer-to-member-function, as well as a pointer-to-member. In addition, you'll need to write a `CompareMember` that compares pointer-to-members, similar to how `CompareFunctor` compares pointer-to-member-functions:

```
// compare pointer to member function
template <class R, class T>
struct CompareFunctor {
    R (T::*fp)() const;
    bool operator() (const T& lhs, const T& rhs) { 
           return (lhs.*fp)() < (rhs.*fp)();
    }
};

// compare pointer to member
template <class T, class M>
struct CompareMember {
    M T::*mp;
    bool operator() (const T& lhs, const T& rhs) { 
           return lhs.*mp < rhs.*mp;
    }
};

// helper function : compare pointer to member function
template <class R, class T>
CompareFunctor<R,T> make_compare_functor(R(T::*fp)() const) {
    return CompareFunctor<R,T> { fp };
}

// helper function : compare pointer to member 
template <class T, class M>
CompareMember<T, M> make_compare_functor(M T::*mp) {
    return CompareMember<T, M> { mp };
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bjefTW).

Note that I added `const` to the pointer-to-member-function signatures, and corrected a couple of typos in the question's code.

Also `make_compare_functor` should probably be renamed to `make_compare` now that it accepts pointer-to-members as well.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, but I cannot even instantiate the `CompareFunctor` !
try to call: `auto f = make_compare_functor( &Person::get_full_name );` 
It does not compile !

Comment: Did you click on the demo link? It compiles for me.

Comment: aha!  Apparently your version compiles because you declared the function pointer as `const` : ` R (T::*fp)() const;`.
Does that mean that this pointer can only be assigned to and call `const` functions ?

Comment: No, you can use it with non-const functions as well, but you shouldn't since passing a non-const function as a comparator doesn't really make sense.